# Replace $ z z^* $ by $ |z|^2 $

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, complex, algebraic-manipulation

I have a long expression involving different complex numbers. I want to force *Mathematica* to replace `z Conjugate[z]` by `Abs[z]^2` without using polar coordinates in the whole expression. For example,

```
z w Conjugate[z] Conjugate[w] + Conjugate[z] w + z^2
```

should just be 'simplified' to

```
Abs[z]^2 Abs[w]^2 + Conjugate[z] w + z^2
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a repeatedly applied rule

```
z w Conjugate[z] Conjugate[w] + Conjugate[z] w + z^2 //. a_ Conjugate[a_] :> Abs[a]^2
```

> ```
> z^2 + Abs[w]^2 Abs[z]^2 + w Conjugate[z]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The `FullSimplify` function knows how to do that:

```
FullSimplify[z Conjugate[z]]
```

> ```
>  Abs[z]^2
> ```

Comment: Not for a more complex expression, unfortunately.